# Dirty Uninstall of ROS

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am running ROS on Ubuntu 11.04.  I can't remember how I exactly installed ROS but I distinctly remember using svn.  I wanted to make sure my ros was up to date after doing an svn update and a make in my ros folder but I couldn't figure out how to check my installation/version.  So I decided I would uninstall it and start from scratch.  However, I could not find an uninstall script anywhere (I checked rosinstall, and the make file.)  To fix my problem I simply did rm -rf [my ros dir].  I just did a locate and it looks like there's a lot of residue ROS files all over my system ... probably from a "sudo make install."  Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could remove this residue?  (And maybe on how I should have uninstalled it.)  Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10759/dirty-uninstall-of-ros/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2011-07-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-07-28**:
Can you be a little more specific about what residue you are finding.  ROS packages do not define an install target, the current build system only supports building in the current tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed ROS from source then you only need to remove the source code that you downloaded to cleanup ROS.  ROS builds in place in the download tree.  This does not remove any system dependencies (e.g. boost) that may have been installed separately.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0